# how to setup （or maybe storing） Go project with GOPATH

Tags: go

I am not clear of the relationship between GO project with GOPATH. although i have refer so many cases.

I have found there are two solutions

1. reset(or add something new) the GOPATH when there is a new project need to be add
   D:\workspace\golang\calcproj;D:\workspace\golang\golearning;D:\workspace\golang\rpcclient;D:\workspace\golang\rpcserver

[image]

2. just set a only one GOPATH forever, and just modified the code about import
   D:\workspace\golang

[image]

and when i try to follow the solution 2 to setup the project in Window OS, i always get a error info：**can't load package: package calc:**

my GOPATH : E:\GoWorks ， and Go Project file directory is like below：

[image]

i don't like the solution 1，because we need to change the GOPATH every time, when there is a new project~~

Q1. but how to build a project as like the other solution？

Q2. anyway how does GOPATH works ？

Q3. what is the best way to setup the GO project across with GOPATH

Comment: You normally use a single GOPATH for all projects. See [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: I didn’t down vote the question, but this does seem like you should be starting be reading the official documentation first.

Answer (score 1):

How does `GOPATH` work?  `GOPATH` is where go will look for local dependencies to build your application.  This is like the root namespace of your workspace where you are coding.  If you change your code location, you likely will want to change your `GOPATH`, too.

What is the best way to setup the GO project across with `GOPATH`? [This wiki article has your answer](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Setting-GOPATH#windows)

I'd recommend going there and following breadcrumbs if it's moved since I've answered this.  However, in case it's not available as you're reading, this is a snippet

> Your workspace can be located wherever you like, but we'll use C:\work in this example. Note that GOPATH must not be the same path as your Go installation.
>
> - Create folder at C:\work.
> - Right click on "Start" and click on "Control Panel". Select "System and Security", then click on "System".
> - From the menu on the left, select the "Advanced systems settings".
> - Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom.
> - Click "New" from the "User variables" section.
> - Type GOPATH into the "Variable name" field.
> - Type C:\work into the "Variable value" field.
> - Click OK.

I think for your case, you are adding `C:\workspace\golang\...\projectname1;C:\workspace\golang\...\projectname2;...` instead of just using `C:\workspace` as your `GOPATH`.  Keep in mind that this assumes you are using a common namespace for all of your projects, so you'll need to include the `\golang\...` part of the path in your `import` section.  If you want to exclude the `\golang\` part of your package paths, then include that in your `GOPATH`.

Comment: ， so whenever there is a new project to setup， we also need to add the project directory into the GOPATH， is it？  but although the calc.go import "os"
import "fmt"
import "calcproj/simplemath"
import "strconv"  why does it not work ?

Comment: @march_seven No. Keep it simple. Do like How to Writing Go Code (https://golang.org/doc/code.html) tells you to do. Have one and only one entry in GOPATH. Everything from one "project" goes into $GOPATH/src/<projectpath>. You import stuff from "project" A into "project" B by `import "projectpath-of-a"`. Read How to Write GO code _now_. Then once more.

Comment: @Volker as Frandk Bryce show the snippet upstairs， my project is set up into  src/calcproj， and there is two directory below  it ， E:/Goworks/src/calcproj/calc/calc.go and E:/Goworks/src/calcproj/simplemath/add.go ; GOPATH is :E:/Goworks; but it seems not works. (while I delete calcporj directory , it is OK,)  but my purpose is that  calc directory and simplemath directory are the same project which need to put into the same directory.~~~ so could you tell me what is wrong with it ?thanks

Comment: You need to include "calcproj/simplemath" and "calcproj/calc" in your imports

Comment: @FrankBryce  add "calcproj/simplemath" in the calc.go is OK，but when add  "calcproj/calc" in calc.go  imports,  there is a error show in the top of calc,go that package main ====> "can't load package :import cycle not allowed package calcproj/calc"

Comment: You don't need to add a reference to the package that you're currently in